# openform Macro Where criteria

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am using a button from an unbound nav form to open a different form. The button Macro closes the nav form and opens the form I want with no issues.

I have a query that gets a value.

I want to open my form on the value of the query field match to the form's recordsource. The query is not associated with the recordset of the form directly, it's just a way to reference the value. It simply has one field that gets the value I need.

Please suggest some syntax in the where condition of the macro that sets the record of the form I am opening to the value in the query...

I have tried Where Condition= =[qrySeparateIDNUM][IDNUMVALUE]  =Forms!MyForm!FORMIDNUM

not working macro error

EDIT: I have decided to use VBA to do this. OnClick of the unbound nav.  I open the target form AcNormal, but I cant get me.InvoiceID from the form recordset query to open to the matching value. BTW this DOES work when you open a record on the SAME form from a record within the form, but not from an unassociated form like my unbound nav, why?

EDIT Number 2

For everyone's edification, this worked, modify for your use.

Private Sub CommandOpenTarget_Click()

DoCmd.OpenForm "frmMain"

Forms("frmMain").Recordset.FindFirst "INVID = " & Me!ID

End Sub

As to continue my journey into programming I have decided to fully explain this answer in the context of what I was trying to accomplish. Too many times, in this and other forums and resources, many people can not find the answers they are looking for. I have been working on my concurrent projects for more than a year on both of them, because, like I described to June7, I'm not very good yet, even now, but if someone took the time to fully explain what COULD be done and why it works, it helps people stop their endless searching. Include results from a suggestion, and be detailed in your question, and hopefully the people who weigh in will fully explain their solution and describe the results from their suggestion.

The negs, screw you... It was as simple as the above...I don't see anyone else trying to help, but the neg, f*off.

The fact that no one knows this and that no one could answer this befuddles me

Comment: Why do you show a quote character in expression? Appears you have references reversed. Should not need concatenation. `[IDNUM] = Forms!MyForm!DNUM`. However the IDNUM field must be in the form's RecordSource. Directly referencing field of table or query object is meaningless. No way to know which record to pull value from.

Comment: However the IDNUM field must be in the form's RecordSource...it's not. Why is that important? The query refers to the same key value that the form's recordsource is derived from. Can I dim an integer in the form load? Thanks I made an edit. Truth is I'm not very good, and many references to this have been sparse and confusing. What I am doing is unconventional maybe, so some help is why I came here. I want that value for comparison only, is there some other quick way to match the value in the query with the field on the form?

Comment: WHERE CONDITION is to apply filter to form or report, not pull data from a table or query object. How can you set form record with IDNUM criteria if IDNUM is not in form's RecordSource? Or whatever field in form has value that equates to IDNUM. Again, cannot directly reference a table or query in that property. Are you saying qrySeparateIDNUM has only one record? Possibly what you need to use is DLookup() function.

Comment: yes separateidnum has only one value, it is a dmax which returns just one value. can I set a Dlookup in the where condition of the macro OpenForm? why can't I use gotorecord and match the value? and how do I call it in either of the macro's function? I just found browseto will that work?

Comment: Why not use the DMax expression in textbox on form? Why have intermediate query object? No, BrowseTo will not be helpful to pull value from table or query. Perhaps you should post in a forum that allows attaching files and provide your db for analysis.

Comment: June7 thanks. I have edited above, but still, what is not right about my approach? I click a button to open my form and I would like to go to the record that matches the numeric value of the invoice number on the unbound nav, why is this so hard? Form_Load   me!InvIDNUM = qryNextInvID "InvIDNUM" how about some syntax this way? Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

For everyone's edification, this worked, modify for your use.

```
Private Sub CommandOpenTarget_Click()

  DoCmd.OpenForm "frmMain"

  Forms("frmMain").Recordset.FindFirst "INVID = " & Me!ID

End Sub
```

Comment: Is this solution to your issue?

Comment: yes, thanks for looking at my issue.

Comment: Criteria syntax essentially what I offered in first comment under your question but now you show different field name. I have never seen FindFIrst used that way. I would have used RecordsetClone and Bookmarks to accomplish. Actually learned something new.